# selenium 3.6.0 and extensions

Tags: python, selenium, firefox-addon

Note that I edited the question.

How to activate blocking for ghostery extension in firefox through selenium python bindings? Note that by default the blocking in ghostery is disabled. 
I am using selenium 3.6.0 and ghostery 7.3.3.7. Note that I am using selenium + pull request #4790 that allow the new web extensions, because the released version lack this feature.

I do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.add_extension(extension=/home/nsarafij/ghostery-7.3.3.7.xpi)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp)
```

Is it possible to activate blocking in ghostery through setting preferences?

fp.set_preferances(...)

Or, I have to do something different?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand you correctly - you want to add Ghostery to Firefox right?

If so, this should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
ghostery="PATH_TO_GHOSTERY_ADDON"
firefoxProfile.add_extension(ghostery)
firefoxProfile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
```